# Proving that a polyhedron has integer vertices

Tags: polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry, integrality-gap

> Prove that the polyhedron $$ P = \left\{ (x_1, \ldots , x_m, y) \in \mathbb R_{+}^{m+1}: y \leq 1,x_i \leq y \text{ for } i = 1,\dots, m \right\} $$ has integer vertices.

It seems obvious to me but don't know how to prove it. Any thoughts ?

Comment: What exactly would constitute a proof in your mind?

Comment: My first thought is that you should figure out where the vertices are.

Comment: . . . and is this actually a polyhedron?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I was just wondering that myself.  For $m = 1$, this seems just like the portion of the first quadrant above (and including) $y = x$.

Comment: Recall that the vertices of a polytope $P \subset \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ can be characterized as follows:  They are the points $p \in P$ such that for every $\vec{v}\ne 0$ at least one of $p+\vec{v}$ and $p-\vec{v}$ lies outside $P$. Using that it should be easy to show that set of vertices is just $\{0,1\}^m\times\{1\} \cup \{\vec{0}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

We would like to prove that the polyhedron

$$\mathcal P := \bigg\{ \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ y\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{n+1} : \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ y\end{bmatrix} \geq \begin{bmatrix} 0_n\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & -1_n\\ 0_n^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ y\end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix} 0_n\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \bigg\}$$

is *integral*, i.e., it has integer vertices. Since the matrix is an upper triangular [Frobenius matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_matrix),

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & -1_n\\ 0_n^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & 1_n\\ 0_n^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

which is also an integer matrix. Thus, the matrix is [unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix). Since it is also nonnegative,

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ y\end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & 1_n\\ 0_n^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0_n\\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1_n\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

which allows us to conclude that $\mathcal P \subset [0,1]^{n+1}$, i.e., it is *bounded*. From Schrijver's book:

---

[image]

---

Thus, $\mathcal P$ is integral if and only if the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_n & -1_n\\ 0_n^{\top} & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

is [totally unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix). It is easy to prove by exhaustion that the matrix is indeed totally unimodular when $n \in \{1,2\}$. If we can prove that the matrix is totally unimodular also for $n \geq 3$, we then prove that $\mathcal P$ is integral. Chapters 19-21 of Schrijver's book should help.

---

- Alexander Schrijver, [Theory of Linear and Integer Programming](https://books.google.com/books?id=zEzW5mhppB8C), John Wiley & Sons, July 1998.